# How did datetime decide '22' in %y is 2022 and not 1922?

Tags: python, datetime

Example code

```
a = '27-10-80'
b = '27-10-22'
c = '27-10-50'

x = datetime.strptime(a, '%d-%m-%y')
print(x)
y = datetime.strptime(b, '%d-%m-%y')
print(y)
z = datetime.strptime(c, '%d-%m-%y')
print(z)
```

Output:

> 1980-10-27 00:00:00
> 2022-10-27 00:00:00
> 2050-10-27 00:00:00

How did datetime decide the year generated from string using '%y' format. Why did 80 become 1980 while 50 become 2050?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If you're just going to link them to the documentation, at least link to the correct section. The answer is [at the top of that page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html).

Comment: @LeopardShark Oh, it's inside time documentation page. I looked at page about datetime, no wonder didn't find it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python documentation indicates that [strftime/strptime follows the semantics of C](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

> Most of the functions defined in this module call platform C library functions with the same name.

as well as documents the behaviour of `%y`:

> Function strptime() can parse 2-digit years when given %y format code. When 2-digit years are parsed, they are converted according to the POSIX and ISO C standards: values 69–99 are mapped to 1969–1999, and values 0–68 are mapped to 2000–2068.

But we can confirm this behaviour by looking up [STRPTIME(3)](https://man.openbsd.org/strptime.3), for [`%y`](https://man.openbsd.org/strptime.3#_y):

> the year within the current century. **When a century is not otherwise specified, values in the range 69-99 refer to years in the twentieth century (1969 to 1999 inclusive); values in the range 00-68 refer to years in the twenty-first century (2000 to 2068 inclusive)**. Leading zeros are permitted but not required.

emphasis mine.

There is no expressed reasoning for that cutoff, but it is reasonable to think that it stems from the UNIX EPOCH being 1970, with a year of safety margin at the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented under the [comment section of `_strptime.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/_strptime.py#L376-L383).

```
if group_key == 'y':
    year = int(found_dict['y'])
    # Open Group specification for strptime() states that a %y
    #value in the range of [00, 68] is in the century 2000, while
    #[69,99] is in the century 1900
    if year <= 68:
        year += 2000
    else:
        year += 1900
```

Comment: Well, that's going to drop on our feet in 2069. The year 1999 has called, they want their Y2K back.

Comment: @HendrikWiese Y2038 is the much bigger (and closer) threat looming on the horizon. If you're using `%y` in 2022 you're a bit of a knobhead really.

Comment: True. Best is going with iso strings or RFC 3339 anyway. No questions left unanswered.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation of [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

> Function strptime() can parse 2-digit years when given %y format code. When 2-digit years are parsed, they are converted according to the POSIX and ISO C standards: values 69–99 are mapped to 1969–1999, and values 0–68 are mapped to 2000–2068.